# Looping through TextBoxes and RadioButtonLists

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, radiobuttonlist

In my webform I have 6 TextBoxes and 6 RadioButtonLists:

Now I want to send an email to the visitor that whatever they have entered and clicked on that RadioButtonLists. Email part is working fine, but how should I bind my all Textboxes and RadioButtonLists into a String?

I have this code so far:

```
         protected void btnSubmit_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Specify senders gmail address
        string SendersAddress = "test@gmail.com";

        //Specify The Address You want to sent Email To(can be any valid email address)
        string ReceiversAddress = "test@gmail.com";

        //Specify The password of gmial account u are using to sent mail(pw of sender@gmail.com)
        const string SendersPassword = "test";

        //Write the subject of ur mail
        const string subject = "Testing Items";


        List<string> st1 = GetTextBoxesAndRadioButtons();
        //string body = GetTextBoxes();

        try
        {
            //we will use Smtp client which allows us to send email using SMTP Protocol
            //i have specified the properties of SmtpClient smtp within{}
            //gmails smtp server name is smtp.gmail.com and port number is 587
            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient
            {
                Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
                Port = 587,
                EnableSsl = true,
                DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
                Credentials = new NetworkCredential(SendersAddress, SendersPassword),
                Timeout = 3000
            };

            //MailMessage represents a mail message
            //it is 4 parameters(From,TO,subject,body)
            MailMessage message = new MailMessage(SendersAddress, ReceiversAddress, subject, "Test");
            /*WE use smtp sever we specified above to send the message(MailMessage message)*/
            smtp.Send(message);
            Console.WriteLine("Message Sent Successfully");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);

        }
    }


    public List<String> returnList = new List<String>();

    private List<string> GetTextBoxesAndRadioButtons()
    {
        string txt;

        foreach (Control ctr in Page.Controls)
        {

            CallControls(ctr);

        }

        return returnList;
    }

    private void CallControls(System.Web.UI.Control p)
    {
        string returntext = "";

        foreach (Control ctrlMain in p.Controls)
        {
            if (ctrlMain.HasControls())
            {
                /* Recursive Call */
                CallControls(ctrlMain);
            }
            if (ctrlMain is TextBox)
            {
                TextBox txt;
                txt = (TextBox)FindControl(ctrlMain.ID);
                returnList.Add(txt.Text);
            }
            else if (ctrlMain is RadioButton)
            {
                RadioButton rad;
                rad = (RadioButton)FindControl(ctrlMain.ID);
                returnList.Add(rad.Text);
            }
        }


    }
```

Here is the markup for UI:

```
<tr>
        <td class="style4">
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="1. "></asp:Label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="tbShoppingList1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" Height="16px" 
                RepeatDirection="Horizontal" Width="772px">
                <asp:ListItem>CVS</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Food Lion</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Home Depot</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Lowe`s</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Publix</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Target</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Walgreens</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>WinDixie</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Walmart</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:RadioButtonList>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Similarly for next 5 textboxes and RadioButtonLists!

This is not working.

'st1' is not storing anything in it.

Comment: Don't quite understand what you're asking here.

Comment: Page.Controls isn't a recursive list of controls. Rather than comparing the objects, you should probably compare ctr.GetType() with typeof(TextBox). I also don't see the point of instantiating the box object?

Comment: I would brute force this with if statements and move on. (my humble opinion)

Comment: @Gabriel: I know, but I want to know the concept :)

Comment: @John: I updated my code. Hope from this you will a gist.

Comment: it works for me. I updated my code for RadioButtonList. see my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it for both the controls. you can also separate out logic in two different methods. This recursively finds all textboxes and radiobuttons withing page.controls. Declare returnList  variable as global (available to both methods).

```
 public List<String> returnList = new List<String>();

private List<string> GetTextBoxesAndRadioButtons()
{
    string txt;

    foreach (Control ctr in Page.Controls)
    {

       CallControls(ctr);

    }

string finalstring = string.Join(",", returnList.ToArray());
    return returnList;
}

private void CallControls(System.Web.UI.Control p)
{
    string returntext = "";

    foreach (Control ctrlMain in p.Controls)
    {
        if (ctrlMain.HasControls())
        {
            /* Recursive Call */
            CallControls(ctrlMain);
        }
if (ctrlMain is TextBox)
                {
                    TextBox txt = (TextBox)ctrlMain;
                    //txt = (TextBox)FindControl(ctrlMain.UniqueID);
                    returnList.Add(txt.Text);
                }
                else if (ctrlMain is RadioButtonList)
                {
                    RadioButtonList rad = (RadioButtonList)ctrlMain;
                    //rad = (RadioButtonList)FindControl(ctrlMain.UniqueID);
                    returnList.Add(rad.SelectedValue);
                }
    }


}
```

Comment: So basically in my returnList I will have entered text of all textboxes and radiolistbuttons?

Comment: I tried Priyank. But it is not even storing into List<string>. See my updated answer!

Comment: @Priyank: It is giving me this error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at this:                     returntext = txt.Text;

Comment: did you take latest edited code. I do not have any such line in this code as "returntext = txt.Text;"

Comment: Add some validations to the code - like findcontrol does not return null or txt.text/rad.text is not null. It should work eventually.

Comment: @Priyank: I tried with the updated code and also filled textboxes with Values in it. Still its showing me this err: Object reference not set to an instance of an object at returnList.Add(txt.Text);

Comment: when you debug it, does it return textbox control at this line txt = (TextBox)FindControl(ctrlMain.ID); ?

Comment: @Priyank: I check at this line: txt =(TextBox)FindControl(ctrlMain.ID); The value in txt is null

Comment: @Priyank: Sorry, but I have RadioButtonList and under it I have 7 asp:ListItem. So technically am I getting the value from a RadioButton?

Comment: It works like a charm on my side. I updated else if condition for RadioButtonList insted of RadioButton. other than that, it returns me two values in returnlist - one for textbox and one for selected value of radiobutton.

Comment: Try UniqueID to see if it helps you find control. txt = (TextBox)FindControl(ctrlMain.UniqueID);

Comment: I updated the code. try this one. there seems of no need to use FindControl. We can just cast the control.

Comment: @Priyank: Cool, I just checked that my return list has items in it. How do I type cast it to a string? I want this 'returnList' to be inside a string!

Comment: How should I convert List<string> into string?

Comment: use this string finalstring = string.Join(",", returnList.ToArray());

Answer (score 1):

Cast ctr to TextBox

```
if (ctr is TextBox)
            {
                textBoxes.Add((ctr as TextBox).Text);  
            }
```

Or better:

```
var tb = ctr as TextBox;
if( null != tb )
       textBoxes.Add(cb.Text);
```

with the last you avoid calling both is/as.

Answer (score 1):

you need to cast the ctr as a textbox then access the "Text" property rather than calling "ToString".. try:

```
 List<string> textboxes = new List<string>();

         foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
         {
            if (c is TextBox)
            {
               textboxes.Add(((TextBox)c).Text); //oops.. forgot a set of parenthesis had to come back and edit.
            }
         }
```

Cheers,
CEC